# How can I remove a <span></span> and then add another <span> after with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to change border color:

```
$("#input_" + type + "_" + row).css("border-color", "black")
```

How can I first remove any `<span></span>` (if present) that directly follows my input and then add the following:

```
<span class="check-ok"></span>
```

Note that I need it to work even if there is no span directly after then input at first.

Comment: What is your purpose of removing a `span` and then adding another one back? Is it solely to change the class of that `span`, rather it exists or not?

Comment: My problem is I am not sure how to remove and have it work if it may or may not be there.

Comment: @RobB - The problem is that at first there will be no span. It's only after input validation has completed that there will be a span. So there will be nothing to change at the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`.next` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$("#input_" + type + "_" + row)
  .next('span').remove().end()
  .after('<span class="check-ok"></span>');
```

If there is no `span`, `.next` won't select any element and `.remove()` won't just do anything.

If there are **multiple** consecutive `span` elements and you want to remove all of them, you can use [`.nextUntil`  *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/):

```
$("#input_" + type + "_" + row)
  .nextUntil(':not(span)').remove().end()
  .after('<span class="check-ok"></span>');
```

Comment: Will this work okay if there's not already a span directly after the input? I am concerned as I will have one input (with or without a span) followed by others with a span. I don't want to remove the next one if it's not part of the input I have just validated.

Comment: `.next` selects the following sibling **if and only if** it matches the selector. If the next element is an `input` element, `.next('span')` won't select it. Apart from reading the documentation, these are all things you can just try out yourself.